# Install-Module returns errors and does not contain -Scope, -Name or other parameters

Tags: powershell

When I try to use `Install-Module` to install PowerShell modules, it has two issues:

1. it can't install from https://www.powershellgallery.com as their instructions imply (the error is *Module ... was not found in central repository*)
2. many of the basic parameters it should have like `-Scope` and `-Name` are missing

Answer (score 0):

As documented in [this post](https://til.secretgeek.net/powershell/psget_conflicts_with_PowerShellGet.html), an older module called `PsGet` also provides an `Install-Module` that overrides the one provided by PowerShellGet.

This can be solved by deleting PsGet from one (or both) of:

- `%ProgramFiles\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PsGet`
- `$home\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Module`

These locations are listed in [Microsoft's Install-Module documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/install-module#description).